# How do I deploy a MERN application to Docker Hub

Tags: reactjs, docker, mern

Is it possible? I just started using Docker so I'm a little lost.

When I composed my MERN application it gave me three images (server, client and mongo). It seems to Docker Hub will only accept one free image. Is there a way around this?

Could I make it so the client image has access to the server and mongo images and then just deploy client?

Comment: Why would you like to host it on docker hub?

Comment: I'm trying to host it somewhere free if possible. I'm new to this so I'm not sure where the best place to host it is.

Comment: Docker hub is a place where you can host your docker image, not a website AFAIK

Comment: Okay. Do you have another suggesting as to where I could upload my site?

Comment: I would think of vercel

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for the [DevOps SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/), or maybe [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).